# how to fix NumberFormatException in android

Tags: android

```
private void increaseFontSize() {
        String getSelction = getset.getFontSize();
        int get_selection = Integer.parseInt(getSelction);
        final CharSequence[] textSize = { "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large",
                "Huge" };
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailPage.this);
        alert.setTitle("Text Size");
        alert.setSingleChoiceItems(textSize, get_selection,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (textSize[which] == "Tiny") {
                            getset.setFontSize("0");
                            restartData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else if (textSize[which] == "Small") {
                            getset.setFontSize("1");
                            restartData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else if (textSize[which] == "Medium") {
                            getset.setFontSize("2");
                            restartData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else if (textSize[which] == "Large") {
                            getset.setFontSize("3");
                            restartData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else if (textSize[which] == "Huge") {
                            getset.setFontSize("4");
                            restartData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    private void restartData() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                DetailPage.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        alert.show();

    }
```

this is function fro set fontsize of text view i have create dialog for select text size . but i am getting NumberFormatException at line  String getSelction = getset.getFontSize();
        int get_selection = Integer.parseInt(getSelction);  please tell me how to fix it while i have  in GLobaldata class

```
String fontSize;

    public String getFontSize() {
        return fontSize;
    }

    public void setFontSize(String fontSize) {
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }
```

i have take fontsize as string and make set and get please how to fix this NumberFormatException .

Answer (score 2):

You have to do two thing.

### 1st thing:

Used `.equals()` for `String` comparison. Like so

```
if (textSize[which].equals("Tiny")) {
```

### 2nd thing:

Also before `parseInt()` check whether your `String is empty or not`. Like so

```
 if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(getSelction)){

 int get_selection = Integer.parseInt(getSelction);

  }
```

Comment: @user1531170 First you tell me  `getset.getFontSize();` ? What does this line?

Comment: class which extends application class where i set and get the ste font size

Comment: @user1531170 and what is the `Default value`?? set it like `String fontSize="1";`

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/pARQ8Rcz9ZssgJfCYeSAkU  this i have use but now when i select other choice then same Exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75468/discussion-between-user1531170-and-m-d).